# How to open many connections at the same time with mongo database

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core

I build .NET Core 2.1 websites and Mongo DB, driver, and deploy at an AWS server in Ubuntu OS at Nginx web server

The problem is the website is down when traffic is increased to 1400 user.
.Net core log is empty and service is up and running.
and Nginx is up and running.

but database log open many connections at the time

Database Log:

```
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32768 #50628 (999 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32770 #50629 (1000 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32772 #50630 (1001 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32774 #50631 (1002 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32776 #50632 (1003 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32778 #50633 (1004 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32780 #50634 (1005 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.545+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32782 #50635 (1006 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.546+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32784 #50636 (1007 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.546+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32786 #50637 (1008 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.546+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32788 #50638 (1009 connections now open)
2019-04-05T10:41:51.552+0000 I NETWORK  [listener] connection accepted from 10.142.0.4:32790 #50639 (1010 connections now open)
```

C# Method to connect to the database:

```
     private IMongoDatabase Connect(string con)
    {
        try
        {
            lock (padlock)
            {
                if (_db == null)
                {
                    var mongoConnectionUrl = new MongoUrl(con);
                    var seetings = new MongoClientSettings
                    {
                        Server = new MongoServerAddress(mongoConnectionUrl.Server.Host, mongoConnectionUrl.Server.Port),
                        WaitQueueSize = 10000,
                        MaxConnectionPoolSize = 500,
                        Credential = MongoCredential.CreateCredential(mongoConnectionUrl.DatabaseName, mongoConnectionUrl.Username, mongoConnectionUrl.Password),
                        ConnectTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60),
                        SocketTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                        MaxConnectionIdleTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),

                    };
                    void SocketConfigurator(Socket s) => s.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);
                    seetings.ClusterConfigurator = builder =>
                        builder.ConfigureTcp(tcp => tcp.With(socketConfigurator: (Action<Socket>)SocketConfigurator));
                    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(seetings);

                    var database = client.GetDatabase(mongoConnectionUrl.DatabaseName);

                    var pack = new ConventionPack();
                    pack.Add(new CamelCaseElementNameConvention());
                    pack.Add(new IgnoreIfDefaultConvention(true));
                    pack.Add(new IgnoreExtraElementsConvention(true));
                    ConventionRegistry.Register("camel case", pack, t => true);
                    _db = database;

                }
            }

            return _db;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error While connecting to db");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are supposed to use only one MongoClient instance for the whole application (if you have one database/mongo cluster).
Depending on how often you call your Connect method, the following line could lead to too many open connections:

```
MongoClient client = new MongoClient(seetings);
```

The Mongo docs say:

> Typically you only create one MongoClient instance for a given cluster and use it across your application. Creating multiple MongoClients will, however, still share the same pool of connections if and only if the connection strings are identical.

In your case, you are using a settings object, so I am not sure if Mongo was able to actually merge all your clients or not, but this should be easily testable.